# Selecting multiple columns from second table in inner join

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, A and B. Table A has columns q, r, and s. Table B has columns s, t, u. I'm trying to get columns q and r from table A, and columns s, t, u from table B. The results need to have a join on column s, which is in both tables.

I've been fiddling with various inner joins, outer joins, and set operations to no avail.

The most recent attempt was

```
SELECT a.account_id, a.created, a.type_id, at.account_name, at.category_id 
FROM accounts a, account_type at 
    INNER JOIN account_type 
    ON a.type_id = at.type_id
```

which gave me the error:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'a.type_id' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 0):

You use excess copy of 2nd table. Must be

```sql
SELECT a.account_id, a.created, a.type_id, 
       at.account_name, at.category_id 
FROM accounts a
INNER JOIN account_type at ON a.type_id = at.type_id
```

or

```sql
SELECT a.account_id, a.created, 
       type_id,    -- not qualified with table alias
       at.account_name, at.category_id 
FROM accounts a
INNER JOIN account_type at USING (type_id)
```

or even

```sql
SELECT a.account_id, a.created, 
       type_id,   -- the only common column name
       at.account_name, at.category_id 
FROM accounts a
NATURAL JOIN account_type at
```

---

> which gave me the error

JOIN precedence is higher than comma one. So your FROM is

```
FROM accounts a, ( account_type at INNER JOIN account_type ON a.type_id = at.type_id )
```

Of course within the parenthesis the column from the outer table is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

> Table A has columns q, r, and s. Table B has columns s, t, u. I'm trying to get columns q and r from table A, and columns s, t, u from table B. The results need to have a join on column s, which is in both tables.

Is this what you need?

```
select 
  A.r, A.t
, B.s, B.t, B.u
from A 
inner join B 
   on A.s = B.s
order by 1 ;
```